# Symfony2 SwiftMailer - How to send emails without waiting for the server response

Tags: php, performance, email, symfony, swiftmailer

I am using swiftmailer to send one single email with about 300 BCC.
The problem is that I am getting a 30sec timeout on the client side when doing this.

When checking on the server side, the mails were sent correctly, but sending all those emails take some time because the mail server deals with a lot of emails.

Any idea on how to tell the swiftmailer not to wait for the server response and render the view.

I checked the [How to Spool Emails](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/spool.html) from the coockbook, but I don't thing that I need to do it this way.

Any idea how could I do that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does a session_write_close in your action can change something ?? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php

Comment: I don't think so. The swiftmailer is sending the email(s) and wiats for the server response for each email, which takes time.

Comment: Spooling emails is exactly what you need here.

Comment: @MichalTrojanowski, thank you. Could you please answer the question anf I will accept

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.gearman.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Symfony Docs:

```
# app/config/config.yml
swiftmailer:
    # ...
    spool: { type: memory }
```

> When you are using the SwiftmailerBundle to send an email from a
>   Symfony2 application, it will default to sending the email
>   immediately. You may, however, want to avoid the performance hit of
>   the communication between Swift Mailer and the email transport, which
>   could cause the user to wait for the next page to load while the email
>   is sending. This can be avoided by choosing to "spool" the emails
>   instead of sending them directly. This means that Swift Mailer does
>   not attempt to send the email but instead saves the message to
>   somewhere such as a file. Another process can then read from the spool
>   and take care of sending the emails in the spool. Currently only
>   spooling to file or memory is supported by Swift Mailer.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/spool.html

Comment: I know, this topic is already pretty old, but I'm facing the same problem as @Miloš was and I tried to handle it by using the memory spool as you suggested. Somehow, it's still taking a lot of time for the emails to get spooled and for a very large number of emails, the server still times out. Is there another way of handling it? A background process? Or at least maybe an ajax-message/flash-message displaying the status of the Sending/Spooling process?